# Primefaces charts replaced by chartJS?

Tags: charts, primefaces, chart.js

Tried PF traditional charts like bar,line and pie. Bar is working. But line and pie did not show. From the showcase, do not have these charts listed on the left menu. Are they replaced by the new chartJS and not supported?

Version 11.0.0.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not removed, they are deprecated since PrimeFaces 10 and will be removed in 13.

See also

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8773